# Setting up apache2 with sym links on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, symbolic-link

While trying to set up Apache2 to locally host several websites on Ubuntu 14.04 for development, I decided to try and use sym links so I wouldn't need to change my directory structure (maintaining everything within folders within a "workspace" folder in the home directory).

The issue is: When trying to access local.mobile.weplann.com or local.desktop.weplann.com, I get a DNS error. I have this set up and working on an OSX system but need it working on this Ubuntu computer as well.

Sym links were set up using `ln -s` within `/var/www/` directory. Permissions should not be an issue as I set all permissions up to the linked directory to look like this: 
`drwxrwxr-x   15 www-data cree         4096 Apr 25 15:01 workspace`

My /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

# local weplann
127.0.0.1 local.mobile.weplann.com
127.0.0.1 local.desktop.weplann.com
```

My virtual host file, titled `weplann.com.conf`, has been enabled and reads as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerAdmin admin@localhost
     ServerName local.desktop.weplann.com
     ServerAlias local.desktop.weplann.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/design/desktop
     ErrorLog /var/www/design/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/design/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory /var/www/design/desktop/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@localhost
     ServerName local.mobile.weplann.com
     ServerAlias local.mobile.weplann.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/design/mobile
     ErrorLog /var/www/design/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/design/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory /var/www/design/mobile/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The "allow from all" was configured as "allow from localhost", but I changed it to troubleshoot the issue.

When I load `localhost` in the browser, it loads the `/var/www/html` directory, another website unrelated to this project. Loading `/var/www/design/desktop` or `/var/www/design/mobile` works to load files from the symbolically linked directory. They don't display correctly, however, as they contain relative links that redirect to `/localhost/path/` instead of `/localhost/design/desktop/path/`.

I deactivated the `000-default.conf` file, which had linked to localhost, so that should not be the problem. No errors are being thrown in the error.log file, and there are no entries in the access.log file unless I go through localhost.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on? (looked at several other stackoverflow/askubuntu threads but couldnt fix this -- posted in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311412/setting-up-apache2-with-sym-links-on-ubuntu-14-04) yesterday as well)